# Conditional law of $X_t | Y_t$ of the Gaussian stochastic process $Z_t=\left( X_t, Y_t\right)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the Gaussian stochastic process (in $\mathbb R^2$ without loss of generality) $Z_t=\left( X_t, Y_t\right)$. What is the conditional law of $X_t | Y_t$ ?

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Z_t = (X_t,Y_t)$ is a [multivariate Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), then $X_t|Y_t$ will also be Gaussian. This can be shown by computing the pdf for $X_t|Y_t$, using the pdf for a multivariate Gaussian, and the formula for [conditional density functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution).